# How to remove Replace Carriage Return and Line Feed using java

Tags: java, carriage-return, linefeed

My target is to remove the **CRLF** from the certificate and append String at the end of the line

[image]

I am using the following code to remove it :

```
 File filename =new File("D:/text.txt");
 RandomAccessFile fw = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
            FileChannel fc = fw.getChannel();
            long oldpos;
            while (true) {
                oldpos = fc.position();
                final String lineFromFile = fw.readLine();

                if (lineFromFile.contains("-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----")) {
                    System.out.println("I found "  +filename.getName());
                    fc.truncate(oldpos + lineFromFile.length());
                    fw.writeBytes(",wirte123");//appends the string to the file
                    break;
                }
            }
            fw.close();
```

String is appended properly and **CR** is removed,but still **LF** exists

[image]

Can please any one help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can't we use 'trim' to remove '\r\n'? or removing CRLF is different ?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code the removes CRLF from the lines. The only thing that your code does is to append a string to the last line of the file (which didn't have a CRLF in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

As you have 2 characters at the end of your line, you should remove both.

So your code should be:

```
fc.truncate(oldpos + lineFromFile.length()-1);
```

Anyway, to avoids surprises I suggest you to check and remove only the proper characters: `\n\r`

`\r` carriage return
`\n` new line or line feed

To do this:

```
lineFromFile.replace("\\n", "").replace("\\r","");
```